# how to insert value of two arrays together in database

Tags: php

Here i my form i am having four checkboxes with each having a textbox for its description

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Sunday"/>Sunday 
    <input type="text" name="description[]" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Monday"/>Monday
    <input type="text" name="description[]" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Tuesday"/>Tuesday
    <input type="text" name="description[]" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Wednesday"/>Wednesday
    <input type="text" name="description[]" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here the user can choose any textbox and can write its description...now at the time of insertion...i want to insert only those values where checkboxes are checked...

For e.g: If i choose monday and tuesday then monday and tuesday should be inserted along with their respectice textboxes....my problem is that when i am submitting then the checkbox values are going right but only single description is getting inserted....here is mmy php script...

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["days"]);$i++)
    {
        $dayz=$_POST["days"][$i];    
        $description=$_POST["description"][$i];      

        mysql_query("insert into transport_two (transport_id,name) values ('$dayz','$description')");    
    }   
}
?>
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: Try to `print_r` `$_POST["days"]` to view the contents of the request.

Comment: i have checked days are going right...but the description is not

Comment: Please include in your question the result of description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why aren't you making your life easier; and giving them a normal non array name?

What you can do is;

```
if ((isset($_POST["days"]) && isset($_POST["description"])) {
 $days = $_POST["days"];
 $desc = $_POST["description"];

 $len = count($days);

 for ($i = 0; $i <= $len-1; $i++) {
    $noID = filter_var($days[$i], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    echo $days[$noID] . " " . $desc[$noID];
 }
}
```

Check if that will work for you :)

**Tested & Working:**

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="days[0][day]" value="Sunday"/>Sunday  <input type="text" name="days[0][value]" />
    <br/><input type="checkbox" name="days[1][day]" value="Monday"/>Monday  <input type="text" name="days[1][value]" />
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="days[2][day]" value="Tuesday"/>Tuesday  <input type="text" name="days[2][value]" />
  <br/><input type="checkbox" name="days[3][day]" value="Wednesday"/>Wednesday      <input type="text" name="days[3][value]" />
```

PHP

```
<?PHP
 $arr = $_POST["days"];
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if (!empty($arr[$i]['day'])) {
    echo $arr[$i]['day'] . " and.... its value is " . $arr[$i]['value'];
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: it is giving this error..Undefined index: in for line $noID = filter_var($days[$i], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    echo $days[$noID] . " " . $desc[$noID];

Comment: Let me run it myself, as I didn't test it. one moment.

Comment: Updated the PHP for you; its completely working: http://bitsource.com.mt/bin/testing/test.html


Due to the fact that it checks if the day is set; no validation is required; as it won't work if the day is not set, and I would add && !empty($arr[$i]['value'] for the if statement to be more precise, and don't forget to put an escape_string on them ;)


And..... don't use mysql_query, its very old. use mysqli instead or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

In php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['chk_group'])) {
    $dayArray = $_POST['days'];
    $decArray =$_POST['description'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($dayArray); $i++) {
        $dayz=$dayArray[$i];
        $description=$decArray[$i];
        mysql_query("insert into transport_two (transport_id,name) values ('$dayz','$description')"); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i choose two checkboxes and filled theiur two coressponding description...both the checkbox values got inserted but only one description got inserted but i filled two

Answer (score 0):

try to use `description[dayname]` in the form and use `$description=$_POST["description"][$dayz]` in processing, you have array indexing issue because checkbox are just not send if not checked.

```
 here i my form i am having four checkboxes with each having a textbox for its description

       <form action="" method="post">

         <input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Sunday"/>Sunday  <input type="text" name="description[Sunday]" />
            <br/><input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Monday"/>Monday  <input type="text" name="description[Monday]" />
        <br/><input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Tuesday"/>Tuesday  <input type="text" name="description[Tuesday  ]" />
          <br/><input type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Wednesday"/>Wednesday      <input type="text" name="description[Wednesday]" />

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

and php:
        if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
       {

```
   for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["days"]);$i++)
    {
       $dayz=$_POST["days"][$i];     
  $description=$_POST["description"][$dayz];        

 mysql_query("insert into transport_two (transport_id,name) values ('$dayz','$description')");   
    }   
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help

```
$str = '';
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["days"]);$i++)
{
   $dayz=$_POST["days"][$i];     
   $description=$_POST["description"][$i];
   $str .= "(".$dayz.", ".$description.")";
   if ((count($_POST["days"])-1) < $i) {
       $str .= ',';
   }         
}
mysql_query("insert into transport_two (transport_id,name) values ".$str) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly name each text input and check-box with different name.

```
  <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="checkbox" name="days1" value="Sunday"/>Sunday 
     <input type="text" name="days1_1" /><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="days2" value="Monday"/>Monday
     <input type="text" name="days2_2" /><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="days3" value="Tuesday"/>Tuesday
     <input type="text" name="days3_3" /><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="days4" value="Wednesday"/>Wednesday
     <input type="text" name="days4_4" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Use this code for checking which check-box are checked.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
     for($i=0;$i<$number_of_days;$i++)
      {
       $dayz="days".$i;    
       $description=$dayz."_".$i;      
        if(isset($dayz))
         {
          mysql_query("insert into transport_two (transport_id,name) values ('$dayz','$description')");     
         }          
      }   
  }
?>
```